# Hyper-V cannot connect to local server (Windows 10 host)

Tags: service, windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am trying to install Hyper-V to create virtual machines to emulate Windows Mobile devices.

I am running Windows 10 Professional, and when I run `systemimage.exe` I see that I should be able to enable Hyper-V features:

[image]

So, I then enabled Hyper-V from "Programs & Features" and rebooted:

[image]

No errors, everything looks fine. But when I run Hyper-V Manager, nothing connects by default, and if I use "Connect to server..." to connect to "Local computer", I get the following error screen:

[image]

All of the Hyper-V services are NOT running, and when I try to start any of them, I get the following:

[image]

( I have set the services to both Manual and Automatic, and it makes no difference.)

So, I am stumped. No errors on install and my workstation should be able to run it fine, but nothing works, cannot even connect to the local host in the Manager.

Comment: you don't have Hyper-V installed, only the management tools. Do you use the 32Bit Win10 Pro`Hyper-V is only available for 64Bit Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise

Comment: @magicandre1981

Comment: ? you missed the important thing in the comment

Comment: @magicandre1981, you can answer this with that.  Nothing I read said it had to be 64-bit Windows 10, it said I needed 64-bit hardware (I thought) and that the systemimage.exe run would tell the tale on availability. Just a bone-headed play on my part, as I am indeed running 32-bit Win10 Pro.

Comment: Not sure why I thought it was just processor that needed to be 64-bit -- a simple search on hyper-v requirements on windows 10 says the OS needs to be 64-bit right at the top. Very sorry to have wasted folks' time!

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer and added a link to the documentation which also shows it requires 64Bit Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the Hyper-V Platform in your Turn Windows on or off dialog

[image]

This means you have a SKU which doesn't support Hyper-V like the Home (Single Language) Edition or you use a 32Bit Windows 10 Pro/Enterprise.

Hyper-V [requires a 64Bit CPU and 64Bit Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/about/hyperv_on_windows).

> **System requirements**
>
> Hyper-V is only available in Windows Professional, Enterprise, and
>   Education editions of Windows 8 and greater.
>
> It requires a 64-bit system that has Second Level Address Translation
>   (SLAT). SLAT is a feature present in the current generation of 64-bit
>   processors by Intel and AMD. **You’ll also need a 64-bit version of
>   Windows**.

So reinstall your PC with a 64Bit DVD to get Hyper-V working, the Windows key works for 32 and 64Bit.

Comment: Thanks again! I probably won't reinstall Windows over this -- I have too much set up on this PC to spend three days just trying to get things back to the way I need them to be. I suppose I could try to image my system and then restore it back ona 64-bit install, but I am not sure how that would work since the 32-bitness is ingrained in the image...

Comment: windows doesn't support 32Bit to 64 Migration. maybe some 3rd party tool support it.

Comment: Yeah, I know it doesn't. I am going to get a new machine, get it on the network, and then remote into it and slowly get everything set up the way I want. Going to upgrade RAM and probably get an SSD in there, plus the 64-bit stuff, obviously. Some backup software will help with that, but you can't restore a 32-bit image into 64-bit land anyway...  As long as I can have both machines on the network and get things transferred and configured, it should work!

Answer (score 3):

Enabling "vmms" from the Services using the Task Manager worked for me.

[image: vmms]

Answer (score 0):

If you have connected to your VM using RDP, perhpas you haven't enabled access to the local filesystem

[image]